# System.DBNull to String error in excel

Tags: c#, excel-addins

I have my own custom file type similar to .CSV except with custom delimiters. The delimiter for the comma is `(char)20` (looks like a square) and for the quotes it is `(char)254` (looks like þ). I have created an Excel 2010 Add-in in Visual studio to parse through the document that replaces all custom delimiters with commas and double-quotes so that it is in .CSV format.

The program also creates a new toolbar and button that will start the process. It works fine on some documents but not on others and if you try to do it twice in one instance of Excel it comes up with  the error `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'string'"`. This is because the `row.Text` property is being read as `{}`.

Now my question is what is causing the `row.Text` property to be read as `{}` instead of the text that is inside the cell? Also why does this occur on some documents but not others even though they use the same encoding?

An example of what is in a cell is (NOTE-the comma symbol won't print here):

```
þITEM_IDþþBEGDOCþþENDDOCþþBEGATTþþENDATTþþPARENT_ATTACHMENTþþATTACHMENT_BATESþþ etc.
```

EDIT Here is my code:

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Office.CommandBarButton toolbarCommand;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Office.CommandBar toolbar = Application.CommandBars.Add("My Toolbar",Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop,false,true);
        toolbarCommand = (Office.CommandBarButton)
        toolbar.Controls.Add(
           Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
           missing,
           missing,
           missing,
           true);
        toolbarCommand.Caption = "Toolbar Button";
        toolbarCommand.FaceId = 59;
        toolbarCommand.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(toolbarCommand_Click);
        toolbar.Visible = true;
    }



    void toolbarCommand_Click(Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
        try
        {
            IterateRows(activeWorksheet);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        Ctrl.Click+=new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(toolbarCommand_Click);
    }

    public void IterateRows(Excel.Worksheet worksheet)
    {
        //Get the used Range
        Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

        Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);

        //Iterate the rows in the used range

        if (usedRange.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            foreach (Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(row.Text);
                char quote = (char)254;
                string data = row.Text;
                row.Columns[1] = data.Replace(quote, '"').Replace((char)20, ',');
                row.TextToColumns(Type.Missing, Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see your code in order to answer your question.